# facebook message notifcation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to make a notification to the user about a new message.
this my code but nothing is happening:

```
<span id"not"><?php echo $nbmsg?>

function updatecontent(){
$('#not span').load('index.php'); 
} 

setInterval("updatecontent()", 5000 );
```

Comment: Your `<span>` has incorrect syntax. It should be `<span id="not">`

Comment: What does Facebook have to do with this?

Comment: and you've forgotten to close the span tag

Comment: @Juhana. Maybe he's a programmer there...

Comment: I would guess his notification is supposed to be similar to Facebook's.I'm sure Facebook would not hire someone who has the wrong syntax on span ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the following errors:

1. `<span id"not">` **=>** `<span id="not">`
2. `$('#not span').load('index.php');` **=>** `$('#not').load('index.php');`

And check the console to see what is going on with the request you send.

One last thing you should change is:

```
setInterval("updatecontent()", 5000 );
```

To:

```
setInterval(updatecontent, 5000 );
```

It's not an error, but it saves you from `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

no need of span, remove `$("#not span");` that is indicating span inside span which have id not

```
function updatecontent(){
   $('#not').load('index.php'); 
}
```